# Which 80s/90s "Outer Limits" or "Twilight Zone" featured two people escaping alien simulator pods?

Tags: episode-identification, the-twilight-zone, the-outer-limits

I've been searching for two hours for the answer but can't find it. I saw many years ago, late 1990's, an episode of possibly *The Twilight Zone* or *The Outer Limits*, in colour, looked late 1980's - early 1990's.

A man and a woman are living inside a simulation and somehow escape it and they're in a really grotty, dank, rundown, dirty, ancient-looking, old metal room, with their two almost triangular pods side-by-side, against the back wall.

There's a heavy metal sliding door to the left and as they open it a huge alien that looks like the soldiers from *Dark Crystal* comes down the corridor and they're trapped, crying when they realise they've been tricked by the aliens.

Comment: Welcome to the site. You have a good start here. If you could take a look at this [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/62201) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details, that would be great. Every little bit helps us.

Comment: ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/To_Tell_the_Truth_(The_Outer_Limits) (seems similar but not quite the description)

Comment: ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dreams_for_Sale - (seems similar but not quite the description)

Comment: @NKCampbell I watched "Dreams for Sale" again a couple days ago, and it's not what's being described.

Comment: Is it perhaps the "Quality of Mercy" episode of Outer Limits?   https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x5veczd